# react-native-image-crop-picker library is causing issue in Google Play Console due to unsupported Application Binary Interface (ABI)

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-image-crop-picker

Google Play Console is giving an error

> Your build configuration targets an unsupported Application Binary
> Interface (ABI). These ABIs are not currently used by active devices.
> To continue using automatic integrity protection, update your build
> configuration so that it only targets these Android ABIs: x86, x86_64,
> armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a.

I am not able to upload the release aab file in Google Play Console. I got to know that `armeabi` causing the issue. But my app `build.gradle` file supports only `x86, x86_64, armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a` ABI.

When I opened release aab in Android Studio to see the contents of the release aab I found that it contains `armeabi libucrop.so`. Due to this, Google Play Console is rejecting .aab file.

**I found that `react-native-image-crop-picker` library is using `ucrop` library which supports `armeabi`. Due to which my release aab contains `armeabi libucrop.so`.**

Kindly help me with this issue.